# Add thead row to Antd table component

Tags: reactjs, antd

#### I would like to add another row in Antd table component, so it will look like this:

[image]

I cannot add the row as a `<tbody>` row since it will get filtered and sorted with the rest of the data. I would like it to be an external part of the table's data.

Placing the inputs within the already existing `<th>` cells is far from a satisfying solution because I would need to hack the CSS quite a lot to make it work, and loose some LESS variables along the way.

#### This is my current try, with form elements inside the first `thead > th`

[image]

To keep the background on the form row only, I would need to have it separated from the first (and only) thead's `<tr>` element to it's own "custom" row.

Does anyone have an idea how implement this design with Antd `<Table>` ?

---

#### I would like the end-result to look like this: (modified via *inspector*)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### First Solution

A wrapper component which manages the state of two `Tables`:

1. The input table with a single row.
2. The data table without a header.

```js
function TableWrapper() {
  ...
  return (
    <Flexbox>
      <Table
        size="medium"
        rowSelection={rowSelection}
        columns={columnsInput}
        dataSource={[{}]}
        pagination={false}
      />
      <Table
        size="medium"
        showHeader={false}
        rowSelection={rowSelection}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={dataSource}
      />
      <Button onClick={handleAdd} type="primary" style={{ margin: '3%' }}>
        Add a row
      </Button>
    </Flexbox>
  );
}
```

[image]

The sorting done by the wrapper, you need at least two items so sort can be called: `dataSource={[{},{}]}`

```js
// columnsInput
    {
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      render: () => <Input />,
      sort: () => // setDataSource...
    }
```

### Second solution

In `dataSource` value which supplied to `Table`, add a **front mock item** and then render row accordingly, for example:

```js
const initial = {
  key: 'initial',
  name: 'initial',
  age: 'initial',
  address: 'initial'
};
```

Then in row rendering:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    render: value => (value === 'initial' ? <Input /> : value)
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    render: value => (value === 'initial' ? <Input /> : value),
    sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    render: value => (value === 'initial' ? <Input /> : value)
  },
  {
    title: '',
    dataIndex: 'action',
    width: '50px',
    render: (_, record) => (
      <>
        {record.name === 'initial' && <Button icon="plus" shape="circle" />}
        {record.name !== 'initial' && (
          <Button icon="delete" shape="circle" type="danger" />
        )}
      </>
    )
  }
];
```

Will result:

[image: ![enter image description here]

in the next component:

```js
function TweakedTable() {
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([makeRow(0)]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setDataSource([...dataSource, makeRow(counter)]);
    setCounter(prev => prev + 1);
  };
  return (
    <Flexbox>
      <Table
        size="small"
        rowSelection={rowSelection}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={[initial, ...dataSource]}
      />
      <Button onClick={handleAdd} type="primary" style={{ margin: '3%' }}>
        Add a row
      </Button>
    </Flexbox>
  );
}
```

No overhead for sorting, just add a `sorter` in table columns.

Moreover your `dataSource` is decoupled from the first row.

[image: Edit SO-56619026-TableHeader]

> Note: I didn't make any state management in the demo, I'm sure you will be able to handle it, also if you want to remove the disabled `Checkbox` you should not use `rowSelection={rowSelection}` and render `Checkbox` on every row and manage them by yourself.

Comment: Another solution is to make a wrapper component which wraps two tables, one single lined with inputs, one with data without header, the wrapper should manage both tables state.

Comment: What do you mean a "wrapper"? I've explicitly said why this method does not work, why did you waste your time providing an answer that does not work and had been already tried & failed (reasons are in the question)?

Comment: I providing you answers with antds components, according to your question you tried to manipulate the styles which is pretty hard with antd. I dont feel that I “wasting my time”

Comment: My suggestions are just pure react, and they work. Anyways feel free to message me if you want to clarify the question, I can help you with the antd part without a problem.

Comment: The moment you filter or sort the table the first editable row will be hidden or moved. Also, you do not want to include presentational row as part of data to is synced with the server

Comment: You can check which rows to not be sorted, and about the data, you can pop the first item but I totally agree that better making separating tables

Comment: Would you like to see the wrapper solution or it's a waste of time?

Comment: I would love to see what you mean by "wrapper", if in your opinion it would be a more elegant solution  (By "waste of time" I was meaning providing a solution I've already tried and think is a no-no)

Comment: @vsync I updated the solution, you can sort the second `Table` by age.

Comment: And btw about what you said earlier about sorting and fetching data with the server: if you do `dataSource=[{},...dataFromServer]` your server data decoupled and you don't need to worry about the extra row.

Comment: I'm not worried about fetching data, but *sending* it. Anyway, I don't understand, using 2 tables, how can the first table's head sorted possible sort the data on the 2nd table... and this will not work for dynamic-width table cells, which is a core concept of table design, where a column's width is determined by the width of the cell with the most content, unless I use fixed values and loose that ability. trust me, none of these solutions will work in real-world app with many product demands

Comment: Yea you right, anyway I think the second one is the better to approach, hope I helped somehow cheers.

Comment: I also want to have an "empty table" default message when there's no data, so if I add "initial" data (for rendering the form) then the `<Table>` will consider it as data I suppose. This is why I really want to add another `<tr>` to the `<thead>`

Comment: You can render antd ‘Empty’ component as a row when needed